# Download HTML page using WebClient issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In Asp.net MVC, I wanted to download a html page content using the url (DownloadString method) so that I can then convert to a PDF. The Html page itself is using JSRender to bind to a template.

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
      string html = client.DownloadString(url);
 }
```

However when I attempt to download the Html from Url, it seems to download the page before the rendering is complete so what I get actually HTML almost pre-render which is not what I want.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve using the WebClient or even indeed from Server side without resorting to do this somehow from Client side?

Answer (score 3):

Webclient doesnt return the html untill the page is fully loaded.

there is a good chance there is a javascript in the page that when it runs, it loads more stuff into the page. so when you download the page, that javascript dont run and as a result, some parts dont get loaded

Comment: That's right, I had to send the user agent as part of the response header.

Comment: did you answer the question yourself and marked your own anwer as the right answer?! :)

Comment: None of them offer the correct answer, because they don't seem to work for the scenario in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static string GetHtmlPage(string strURL)
{
    String strResult;
    WebRequest objRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
    WebResponse objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    return strResult;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(GetHtmlPage("http://www.awardwinnersonly.com"));
}
```

Comment: Ok, I believe I was trying somehting else but this doesn't work and nor does my answer below as the html expected is still not being returned.

Comment: It works for me, so I have no idea what your problem with it is. Do you get any sort of err msg? When you step through it, what happens?

Comment: I'm using JSRender to bind to template and the html I get is the html pre bind. Have you tried using JSRender or Knockout in the view?

Comment: No, the code I show is the entire code; it is a simple utility method. This is not part of a project; it is simple standalone code.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work with use of JSRender I'm afraid.